# Trying to add 2 virtual PC at home that runs off my shop main PC

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc

I had worked at this company and I thought this was the coolest thing and trying to do it for my business.

They gave me a virtual PC I did all my work on and if I was any where a friend’s house out of town where ever I could stick this USB flash drive in that they gave me.

I had to type something, I cant remember, and I could be on my virtual PC at work in seconds, my work PC would right on the screen like if I was at work and it was fast.

Hope I'm making sense.

If someone could steer me in the right direction of what software to use and what setup to use to make it work like this.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Additionally, Microsoft Virtual PC hasn’t been supported for more than 17 years, I don’t believe it will even run on Windows 10.

Comment: I think you are talking about a Remote Desktop client. That is not a virtual PC.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are talking about RDP or similar.  It is not free and you have have a real PC installed somewhere or you have to buy space on a web server.  There are many such offerings

- Microsoft Remote Desktop
- Amazon Web Services
- AnyDesk
- Citrix
- Teamviewer